# Comparing rows in the same R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to take the nth row in a dataframe and compare it to all rows that are not the nth row and return how many of this columns match and/or mismatch.

I tried the match function and ifelse for single observations but I haven't been able to replicate it for the entire dataframe.

The dataset Superstore contains the order priority, customer name, ship mode, customer segment and category. It looks like this:

```
> head(df2)
  Order.Priority     Customer.Name      Ship.Mode Customer.Segment Product.Category
1  Not Specified       Dana Teague    Regular Air        Corporate  Office Supplies
2       Critical     Vanessa Boyer    Regular Air         Consumer  Office Supplies
3       Critical       Wesley Tate    Regular Air        Corporate       Technology
4           High       Brian Grady Delivery Truck        Corporate        Furniture
5         Medium Kristine Connolly Delivery Truck        Corporate        Furniture
6           High       Emily Britt    Regular Air        Corporate  Office Supplies
```

The code I tried (extracting relevant columns):

```
df <- read.csv("Superstore.csv", header = TRUE)
df2 <- df[,c(2,4,5,6,7)]
match(df2[2,],df2[1,],nomatch = 0)
```

This returns:

```
> match(df2[2,],df2[1,],nomatch = 0)
[1] 0 0 3 0 5
```

Using ifelse I get:

```
> ifelse(df2[1,]==df2[2,],1,0)
  Order.Priority Customer.Name Ship.Mode Customer.Segment Product.Category
1              0             0         1                0                1
```

Like I said, this is exactly the result I need, but I haven't been able to replicate for the whole dataframe.

Comment: You need to use `all` for `ifelse`. Try `ifelse(all(df2[1,]==df2[2,]),1,0)`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the all function did that, but what I need is the specific columns that cause the mismatch between rows. If I make df2[1,1]==df2[-1,1] I get a vector with nrow-1 true or false values, and I want to do this for all rows and columns.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your expected output?